Error when I'm trying to build an android app using flutter
The error is the following:
e: /Users/Houssame/.gradle/aches/transforms-3/e5c5aa35234c44d5264fd87af440dbf9/transformed/fragment-1.7.1-api.jar!/META-INF/fragment_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update the  │
version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of
/Users/Houssame/Desktop/demo 3/android/settings.gradle.
Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19), update
/Users/Houssame/Desktop/demo 3/android/build.gradle
ext.kotlin_version = ''
I did upgrade all the version for Gradle but I have the same error, the app is ruining normally in emulator Android Studio.
Android/build.gradle

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.20'
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Android/app/build.gradle

plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'kotlin-android'
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
localProperties.load(reader)
}
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = "1"
}
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}
android {
namespace = "com.Inventory.App"
compileSdk = 34
ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
defaultConfig {
applicationId = "com.Inventory.App"
minSdk = 21
targetSdk = 34
versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName = flutterVersionName
}
buildTypes {
release {
signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
}
}
}
flutter {
source = "../.."
}
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
}

Android/settings.gradle

pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
def properties = new Properties()
file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
return flutterSdkPath
}()
includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
gradlePluginPortal()
}
}
plugins {
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
}
include ":app"

Thank you!

Copy these as they are: edit your aplicationId and namespace to match your applicationId

**android/app/build.gradle**

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "xxxxx"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies { 
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.0' 
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0' 
}

**android/build.gradle**
buildscript { 
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20' 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        mavenCentral() 
        }

dependencies { 
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" 
   
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

**android/setting.gradle**
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.5.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.20" apply false
}


include ":app"


**your gladle-wrapper.properties**
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip


try flutter clean
delete folder inside android/gradle
And try to build again. if didn't worked try downgrading kotlin version to 1.7.10 or 1.8.0
